# I'm getting an [] isn't defined for Object error in dart when I'm trying to follow this Flutter Firebase tutorial?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
List<Sport?> _sportListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot){
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc){
      return Sport(
         name: doc.data['name'] ?? '',
         sport: doc.data['sport'] ?? '',
         age: doc.data['age'] ?? 0
      );

    }).toList();
}
```

I'm getting this error underneath ['name'], ['sport'], and ['age'] and I don't know how to fix it because for the guy in the tutorial, it's not giving him this error?

This is my Sport class:

```
class Sport {
   final String name;
   final String sport;
   final int age;

   Sport({required this.name, required this.sport, required this.age});
}
```

Comment: Can update your question and you paste the exact error in a code block?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation [`QuerySnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html) is actually of type `QuerySnapshot<T extends Object?>` so all the analyzer knows that each `data` property for each document is an `Object` at least. You need to supply more information by either defining the generic like:

```dart
List<Sport?> _sportListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot){ ...
```

Or cast it in the body of the callback like:

```dart
List<Sport?> _sportListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot){
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc){
      final data = doc.data as Map<String, dynamic>;
      return Sport(
         name: data['name'] ?? '',
         sport: data['sport'] ?? '',
         age: data['age'] ?? 0
      );

    }).toList();
}
```

The tutorial probably has relaxed analyzer rules, which is a disservice to the audience in my opinion.

Comment: That didn't fix my error, maybe because age is not a string variable?